# Cypress code coverage plugin with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, cypress

I'm trying to make the [@cypress/code-coverage](https://github.com/cypress-io/code-coverage) plugin work with TypeScript in my project, currently without success. Here are the detailed steps that I tried until now:

- Done all the instructions from https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support
- Added to root folder .eslintrc.json:

```
  "plugins": [
    "cypress"
  ],
  "env": {
    "cypress/globals": true
  },
```

- Changed cypress\support\index.js to index.ts and added:

`import '@cypress/code-coverage/support';`

- Changed cypress\plugins\index.js to index.ts and added:

```
/**
 * @type {Cypress.PluginConfig}
 */
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  // `on` is used to hook into various events Cypress emits
  // `config` is the resolved Cypress config

  require('@cypress/code-coverage/task')(on, config);

  // It's IMPORTANT to return the config object
  // with any changed environment variables
  return config;
};
```

Now for the errors I got from the above step:

`module.exports =` changed to `export default`

`(on, config)` changed to:

```
(
  on: Cypress.PluginEvents,
  config: Cypress.PluginConfigOptions
)
```

Changed `require('@cypress/code-coverage/task')(on, config);` to `import('@cypress/code-coverage/task')(on, config);`

This is the part where I'm stuck now and don't know how to handle this error:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module '@cypress/code-coverage/task'. 'c:/repo/test-app/frontend/node_modules/@cypress/code-coverage/task.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/cypress__code-coverage` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module '@cypress/code-coverage/task';`ts(7016)
```

Please help me resolve the above issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can see that **@cypress/code-coverage** is all in js

```
$ ls node_modules/@cypress/code-coverage/
    common-utils.js  LICENSE.md  middleware/  node_modules/  package.json  plugins.js  README.md  support.js  support-utils.js  task.js  task-utils.js  use-babelrc.js
```

so effectively, you should install **@types/cypress__code-coverage** to make your project in **ts** to understand this **js not typed library**.

Once you has installed this library you obtain how they are typed this function

```
npm i --save-dev @types/cypress__code-coverage
```

Having a look to

```
$ cat node_modules/@types/cypress__code-coverage/task.d.ts 
/// <reference types="cypress" />

export default function registerCodeCoverageTasks(on: Cypress.PluginEvents, config: Cypress.PluginConfigOptions): void;
```

Finally, you change in your

```
cypress.config.ts

import * as registerCodeCoverageTasks from '@cypress/code-coverage/task';
```

that wasn't working for this

```
import registerCodeCoverageTasks from '@cypress/code-coverage/task';
```

and there should be everything ready to compile.

Hope this help you :)